# Difference between create-lwc-app and SFDX cli

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, lightning-web-components

Hello Salesforce community,

I'm not sure where to ask the question so I'll ask it here. 
I'm beginner with LWC and Salesforce (but senior as frontend developer).

Can you explain me the difference with SFDX cli and create-lwc-app / lwc-services ones?

I really like the architecture of lwc-services, it feels like home (npm, webpack etc), you can use require with async await...

What are the difference with local development of SFDX https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/announcing-lwc-local-development-beta.html ?

How to deploy an app created with create-lwc-app and use SF services with @wire?

To summarize my main confusion is between this 2 websites:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_sfdx_hello_world
- https://lwc.dev/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 questions here.

The first one:

> 1. What are the difference with local development of SFDX https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/announcing-lwc-local-development-beta.html ?

This is from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/lwc/localdev) (emphasis mine):

> Local Development enables you to build, run, and test your Lightning Web Components **without deploying your code to your Salesforce org**.

As it mentions, you don't need a Salesforce Org to be able to validate the components you are building but can do so on a local server.

---

The other part of your question is as:

> 2. To summarize my main confusion is between this 2 websites:
>
>    - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_sfdx_hello_world
>    - https://lwc.dev/

For the difference between these two, at a very high level:

[Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_intro.htm) (SFDX) is targeted to build & deploy components directly in a Salesforce Environment. So you will create a component locally, deploy it to a Salesforce sandbox and be able to test that out using this.

> Salesforce Developer Experience (DX) is a new way to manage and develop apps on the Lightning Platform across their entire life cycle. It brings together the best of the Lightning Platform to enable source-driven development, team collaboration with governance, and new levels of agility for custom app development on Salesforce.

On the other hand, [LWC Open Source](https://lwc.dev/guide/introduction) is different that Local Development. LWC Open Source is an *Open Sourced* version the [Salesforce Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_introduction) framework which allows one to be able to build & deploy ***locally*** or ***any platform other than Salesforce***. Below is the excerpt [from the docs](https://lwc.dev/guide/introduction):

> Build apps anywhere, any way. You can build an app with your favorite tools, like Webpack, TypeScript, and Babel, and run it on Heroku, Google, or anywhere else. You can also package an app to create a desktop experience in Electron.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
Since I have to work with SF plateform I'll go with SFDX. (too bad, I really prefer `create-lwc-app` approach with webpack!)
I also had an explanation here: https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app/issues/397